# SSL Enabled MarkLogic DB returns empty result for query execution

Tags: rest, http, ssl, sparql, marklogic

I have Marklogic server with SSL enabled.
Executing the SPARQL query with Java Client API will return empty result. I mean the response body is empty having empty bindings.
The same query run with query console is able to get the expected result, and if I disable SSL and execute with the Java Client API it returns the correct result.

No issues seen in Handshake, cert are correct, and no error related to connection are seen in log file.

Can some one please help me to understand what might wrong with ML connection or any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same used for each way that you have tested (Query console, with SSL, without SSL)?

Comment: yes am sure all same query , same db

Comment: Can you try testing the same operation using curl against this endpoint - https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/graphs/sparql ? That will help isolate the error to just the Java Client. Also, which version of the Java Client are you using? Finally, if the operation works with curl, please open an issue at https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api .

Comment: @rjrudin
curl based sparql run for ssl enabled db returns empty bindings {"head":{"vars":[]},"results":{"bindings":[]}}   ( marklogic client api version : 4.1.2)

Comment: @user092 Can you confirm that the `app-server` used in `query console` and `Java Client API` are the same?

Comment: @P K , Yes Same